# NSJSONSerialization json object leads to annoying empty XCode debug variables

Tags: ios, json, xcode, debugging, serialization

I'm using NSJSONSerialization's JSONObjectWithData method to serialize json response data into a NSDictionary hierarchy, as part of my API handling in IOS.  This works great.  The long standing tedious part however is that when using the XCode debugger, the nested json data structure is not viewable in the variable watcher.   This can best be seen in the photo at the end.  The data is all accessible and navigable in the code, it just isn't for the debugger.

Is there any way to clean this up or serialize it better?

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){
    if (error){
        NSLog(@"Request Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        if(completionHandler != nil){
            completionHandler(nil,error);
        }
    } else {
        NSError *jsonerror = nil;
        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&jsonerror];
        if(jsonerror) {
            NSLog(@"JSON Serialize Error: %@", [jsonerror localizedDescription]);
            if(completionHandler != nil){
                completionHandler(nil,jsonerror);
            }
        } else {
            if(completionHandler != nil){
                completionHandler(json,nil);    // usual successful json route
            }
        }
    }
}];
```

[image]

Comment: Could you print the Json as string to see how data looks?

Comment: At a breakpoint in your code, switch to the "console" pane (where the NSLog info prints) and type `po jsonResp`.  This will print the same image you'd see if you NSLog `jsonResp`.

Comment: I currently print the json out on load, however it tends to be quite long. Being able to use the debugger to quickly find fields and navigate the hierarchy would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try using AFNeteorking for serialization. 
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

It might help. 
If not you can print what ever you need in the console part of the debugger using po.

po object

For example